# pdb.set_trace() causing frozen nosetests, does not drop into debugger

Tags: python, pdb, nosetests

I'm running a suite of tests (.py files) using nosetests.  Using a classic

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

the nosetests run just never completes.  It just hangs right where the breakpoint has been set, but never drops into the pdb debugger.

Any ideas why this would be?  I've tried moving the breakpoint to a number of different positions (other test functions, other files) to no avail.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Run nose with the `-s` / `--nocapture` option and you'll be able to see the pdb prompt and interact with the debugger normally.

If using the commandline that means:-

```
python manage.py  test -s [other-opts-and-args]
```

Comment: sure enough!  Thanks Mike!  Didn't realize no options would make it just swallow everything

Comment: if you have setup.cfg, under [nosetests] add a line 'nocapture = 1'

Answer (score 39):

Nose is capturing the output and redirecting it.  So, the breakpoint is hit, but you just don't see it.  You need to turn off the output redirection so that the debug output shows up on the screen.

Nose can do this for you, if you use:

```
from nose.tools import set_trace; set_trace()
```

instead of:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: @CrazyGeek did you get a solution for this? BdbQuit?

Comment: Nope, I don't remember exactly, What solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the flag the flag -s/--nocapture, still didn't resolve it and drop the compiler into pdb.

One other reason that you could look into is if you're using a database such as MySQL as part of your tests, that it's not locked by another simultaneous process. In my case, i had started a python shell to query the MySQL database through SQL Alchemy and that had locked up the tables. As a result, my nose tests were hanging - not running/exiting.

I killed the python processes which were locking up the tables and Nose was back up sniffing

**> $ ps auxww | grep python | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -9**